# Regular expression with variable number of characters

Tags: javascript

I have a string as follows in lightning component controller.
`var s1 = Q9954,85610`
I have the following valid scenarios for the string , no leading or trailing commas or white spaces:

- Q9
- Q9,85
- Q9954,85
- 85,85610
- Q9954,85610

The following are the Invalid scenarios:

- Q9,1
- Q9, 8
- Q9,85,4
- Q9, 85, 4
- 8,Q,
- Q,Q

I have the code to eliminate leading and trailing commas and white spaces in the above scenarios. I am looking how to form a regular expression which takes care of valid and Invalid scenarios.

Here is a piece of code I am currently using.

```
<lightning:input label="" minlength="2" maxlength="18"  pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+" aura:id="code" onchange="{!c.someMethod}" messageWhenPatternMismatch="Invalid Code" value=""/>
```

I need an regular expression which will accept all the above valid scenarios so I can replace the above regex with the new one. The new regex can accept 2 characters or 5 characters or 8 or 11 characters.
Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Why does it need to be a regular expression? Would it not be easier to simply split the text at commas and use [string.startsWith](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) against each segment from both arrays, then check that each segment is either 2 or 5 characters long in the "to be checked" value?

Comment: BTW, my above comment is based on the assumption you want to see if text matches your `s1` variable value in parts. But I'm wondering if I have misunderstood your question and that you simply want to validate that the input string is a sequence of comma delimited alphanumeric segments of 2, 5, 8 or 11 characters separated by commas...?

Comment: Please do try to include in your posts an explanation of what you've tried so far to solve the specific question you're asking about. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a regular expression that validates an input as:

"One or more sequences of alphanumeric characters that are 2, 5, 8 or 11 characters long, separated by commas"

Then the following regex will work for you:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{11})(,([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}))*$
```

This matches 2, 5, 8 or 11 alphanumeric characters followed by 0 or more repeats of a comma followed by 2, 5, 8 or 11 alphanumeric characters.

Comment: I decided not to go with an regular expression, rather handle it in the code itself.anyways thanks for your comment